# Yii2 как получить доступ к User Identity в модуле?

Tags: yii2, yii

Есть модуль modules/admin/Module.php по каким то причинам свойство \Yii::$app->user->identity говорит null, хотя если обращаюсь к нему в не модуля например в контроллере то в udentity лежит вся информация о пользователе. Что делаю не так?

Собственно задача сводится к тому чтобы ограничить доступ к модулю некоторой группе пользователей, каким образом этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно задать пользователя для отдельного модуля.

Global cofig:

```
...
'modules' => [
    'mymodule' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\mymodule\MyModule',
    ],
    ...
```

MyModule class:

```
class MyModule extends \yii\base\Module
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    \Yii::configure([
        'components' => [
            'user' => [
                'class' => 'yii\Web\User',
                'identityClass' => 'app\modules\mymodule\models\MyUser',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Usage:

```
Yii::$app->getModule('mymodule')->user
Yii::$app->getModule('mymodule')->user->identity
```